# vba if file exists then delete

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a text file where it contains part of the previous dates month in the file name title and the current year.

so for instance if today is November this would be month number 11 and last month would be month number 10.

so I want to delete the file where it contains month number 10 because this is the previous month.

for some reason my code causes excel to crash and not respond, can someone please show me how I can alter my code to get this working, thanks

```
Dim iMonth As Integer
Dim iYear As Integer
iMonth = Month(Date) - 1
iYear = Year(Date)
Dim DirFile As String
DirFile = "P:\Log (" & iMonth & "-" & iYear & ")*.txt"
Do While DirFile <> ""
Count = Count + 1
Loop
If Count > 0 Then
SetAttr DirFile, vbNormal
'Then delete the file
Kill DirFile
End If
```

Comment: You might get better behaviour using a Scripting.FileSystemObject which is a standard COM object in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your giving the string DirFile a value then creating a while loop that loops while the string DirFile is not blank, so it will run forever (locking up excel),  you will need code that will check if the file actually exists and then delete it

```
DirFile = "P:\Log (" & iMonth & "-" & iYear & ")*.txt"
Do While DirFile <> ""  'always true
Count = Count + 1
Loop
```

Try use

```
Dim iMonth As Integer
Dim iYear As Integer
iMonth = Month(Date) - 1
iYear = Year(Date)
Dim DirFile As String
DirFile = "P:\Log (" & iMonth & "-" & iYear & ")*.txt"

    If Len(Dir(DirFile)) <> 0 Then
        SetAttr DirFile, vbNormal
        Kill DirFile
    End If
```